# error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "uint8_t *"

Tags: c, keil, hal, nucleo

I'm trying to write a I2C application with HAL on STM32F401RE. When I write data, I get this error. Here is my code.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint16_t MemAddress, uint16_t MemAddSize, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)

HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(hi2c, MPU9250_ADDRESS, PWR_MGMT_1, 0x01, 1, 100);
```

Where 0x01 is must be (uint8_t *) form. How can I convert or cast it?

Comment: Don't tag a question with both C and C++ unless you like down-votes or are asking specifically about the difference between the way C and C++ works.  Choose one language tag (for the language you're learning) and stick with it.

Comment: `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write` seems to take 7 arguments but you are only giving 6.

Comment: you are right. in the code i wrote HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(hi2c, address, subAddress, 1, data, 1, 100); but there is a few errors about uint8_t*

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `0x01` (a value of type `int`) to a function expecting a `uint8_t*`. (the `*` means that it is expecting a pointer not a value.) Which isn't possible as you can't point a pointer to a variable that doesn't exist.

You need to add a variable with that value and pass it as:

```
uint8_t data = 0x01;
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(hi2c, MPU9250_ADDRESS, PWR_MGMT_1, &data, 1, 100);
```

Comment: @FurkanMola, if you want a real answer to your question then you need to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or in other words. Add the smallest function for you have for the thing you want to do. I can't answer why multiple variables are defined because I don't see any being defined.